# Transition text from below a background image

Tags: html, css, transition

Problem: 
I have no idea how to make a nice `hover/transition` within the profile picture of each person

I want additional information of the person to appear/slide in from below when someone hovers over the picture-circle.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEQdJ.jpg

I'm making an about-us page as a school project.  Been thinking about may be some z-index trickery or opacity.

Comment: check out CSS transform, transition and animation help documents... you should get plenty of ideas whilst going through them

Comment: Before posting here you should read how to ask -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Basically you should include code in your answer. Code that replicates your problem and what you have tried to solve it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/17/Batman-BenAffleck.jpg/200px-Batman-BenAffleck.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hi I'm Batman</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Try the following. I guess this is what you are looking for. I made use of pure css for this. On hover, the text rises from the bottom. I made use of an overlay class and I made use of image border-radius to get the rounded shape you were looking for.

You can read more about these tricks [here.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed! :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Have a good day. ;)